# Django unable to find JS static scripts

Tags: django

I have a basic Django app that I am trying to add HTML to.

The issue I am having is that for some reason my markdown is not picking up the `scripts` in my `static` folder.

I'm relatively new to `Django` so I've included what I think is relevenant.

Static folder structure in the project root.

```
-- static
---- css
------ some_css_files
---- images
---- scripts
------ some_scripts
```

Reference scripts in HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
<head>

    {% load static %}
...
...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts/plugins.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'scripts/functions.js' %}"></script>
```

From Chrome dev tools, the path looks correct, with the `static` folder being looked for in the root, but still 404 on all the resources.

```
0.0.0.0/:13 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/css/bootstrap.css 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:14 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:15 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/css/swiper.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:16 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/css/dark.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:17 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/css/font-icons.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:18 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/css/animate.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:19 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/css/magnific-popup.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:21 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/app/content/responsive.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:221 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/scripts/jquery.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:222 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/scripts/plugins.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
0.0.0.0/:223 GET http://0.0.0.0:8000/static/scripts/functions.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

In my `settings.py` I have the below for static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

What have I misconfigured or do I need to change in order to get resources picked up ok?

UPDATES:

root urlpatterns

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='home/', permanent=True)),
    path('home/', include('home.urls')),
]
```

Comment: show us your root urlpatterns

Comment: @iklinac, added that in

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Answer (score 1):

You can see that all of your static files are not loaded including css

For development you should add additional static urlpatterns as noted in [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

> ```
> from django.conf import settings
> from django.conf.urls.static import static
>
> urlpatterns = [
>     # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
> ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
> ```

Or if you use default `django.contrib.staticfiles`  set

```
DEBUG=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your referencing script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/plugins.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/functions.js"></script>
```

Comment: @3therk1ll have you mentioned this in your question.??? before voting down you should check your question first.

Comment: I never voted it down. The markdown I have is the equivalent of what you have suggested and I did check

Comment: You can see from dev tools that url paths are correctly generated so your answer is not helpfull, also there is no point of hardcoding static urls